# How to get the list of all @Test annotation methods from test source package

Tags: testing, annotations

I'm working on a project where in all the test classes in a package 
will populate in UI where in I can select any of the class and run. 
Now I want to extend it to test methods run. For this I need to 
retrieve all test methods in a test class.I found following class which will give me test classes.But the problem is ,i am easily getting all @Test methods from src/main/java packages ,not from src/test/java.it can't recognize the test source package.

I have applied the below code and it can give me all class names and method names which contains @Test methods.But it is not applicable to find out the class & method names from src/test/java of maven project.

public static Set> getClassesFromPackage(String packageName) {
        Reflections reflections = new Reflections(packageName, new SubTypesScanner(false));
        return reflections.getSubTypesOf(Object.class);
 }

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    for ( Class c: getClassesFromPackage("SourceMainJavaPackageName" )){

            Method[] methods = c.getMethods();
            for (Method method : methods) {                 
                for (Annotation annotation : method.getDeclaredAnnotations()) {
                    if (annotation.annotationType().equals(org.junit.Test.class)) {
                        count++;
                    }
                }
            }               

               }
}
```

i want @Test method names and corresponding class names from src/test/java.

Comment: Because code in `src/main/java` cannot see code in `src/test/java` put this main method in a class in `src/test/java`.